# Android: Struggling to get a Drawable working in an emply ImageView

Tags: java, android

Java on Android: I am trying to input a Drawable into an empty ImageView but it just does not work. Literally anything I tried under the "if"'s is not working.
Sorry if this sounds really stupid I've been at this for way too long (It's school work).

When I try to run the Emulator I get the Error "Name_of_project keep stop"

```
public class Robot extends AppCompatActivity {
    Boolean info;
    private ImageView ivRobot;
    Drawable[] imgs = new Drawable[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_robot);
        Intent RobotI = getIntent();
        info = RobotI.getBooleanExtra("info", false);
        imgs[0]=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.robot,null);
        imgs[1]=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.notarobot,null);
        if (info==true) {
            ivRobot.setImageDrawable(imgs[0]);
        }
        else if (info==false) {
            ivRobot.setImageDrawable(imgs[1]);
        }
    }

    public void GoBack() {
        Intent Main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(Main);
    }

    public void btnGoBack(View view) {
        GoBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: define "not working", what is the behavior you observe or do you get any error messages (if so, copy them into your question).

Comment: I just did that, my bad

Comment: That message is just the user-facing one. It's not very useful for debugging. Try to get the log output of your application (logcat or Android Studio will be useful for this)

Comment: please share the crash report as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you didn't initialize your ImageView `ivRobot`, so I guess you're getting a `NullPointerException` when you call `ImageView::setImageDrawable`.

Try initialize your `ImageView` like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_robot);
        Intent RobotI = getIntent();
        info = RobotI.getBooleanExtra("info", false);

        // todo: put your ImageView id
        ivRobot = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_robot)

        imgs[0]=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.robot,null);
        imgs[1]=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.notarobot,null);
        if (info) {
            ivRobot.setImageDrawable(imgs[0]);
        }
        else {
            ivRobot.setImageDrawable(imgs[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this was such a rookie mistake...